# C# . I need to find shortest words in every lines(from file)

Tags: c#, string, char, lines

I need to find shortest words in every lines with condition that these words shouldn't be shorter than "x"

For example this is the data:

> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset  sheets
>   containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like  Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

and if i write for example x=5;

the result should be:

> Lorem
>
> Aldus
>
> Lorem

I know how to find just the longest words and that's it but how shortest with an condition don't:

```
static string Longest(string line, char[] s, int x)
    {
        string[] parts =line.Split(s,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string longg = "";
        foreach (string word in parts)
            if (word.Length >=longg.Length)
                longg = word;
        return longg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check each word, and will return the word that is greater than or equals `x` and shorter than the `shortWord`.

```
static string Shortest(string line, char[] s, int x)
{
    string[] parts =line.Split(s,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string shortWord = "";
    foreach (string word in parts)
        if (word.Length >= x && (shortWord.Length == 0 || word.Length < shortWord.Length))
           shortWord = word;
    return shortWord;
}
```

**Update**

This is a function that takes a word and an array of letters, and returns the first letter that exists in the word.

```
static char GetLetter(string word, char[] letters)
{
     foreach(var c in word)
         if (letters.Contains(c)) return c;
     return '\0';      // return a default letter if no letters was found. 
}
```

You can call it like (`GetLetter("Lorem", new char[] {'a', 'e', 'o'})`). When you get that letter (i.e. `o` in `"Lorem"`), you can find all words that contain that letter as follow:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (var word in line)
{
    if (word.Contains(c)) result.Add(word);      // c is the letter
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I'm sorry for asking too much, but how i could find another words in these lines that has shortest words vowel letters. For example char[] letters= { 'a', 'e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'Y', 'O', 'U' };  the first word is Lorem so it has first vowel letter 'o', the program should find all words in first line that has a letter 'o'.

Comment: @Ekli I'm not sure about what you want, but if you need a word that contains a specific letter, you can simply use `if (word.Contains(c))`, where `c` is the letter you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
But what if i don't know what letter i'm looking for.
Like i said if the shortest words have any of those letters('a', 'e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'Y', 'O', 'U');
For example word "Lorem" has 'o' and  (ofcourse 'e', but i need the letter which comes first).So i need to find other words which has letter 'o'. So if my first line was  ("It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum")
My result should show all the words that contains 'o', . I don't know how to clarify more clearly. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq for this.

```
return parts.Where(w => w.Length >= x).OrderBy(w => w.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

will get you the shortest word that is at least `x` in length or `null` if none match the requirement.  You can add `?? string.Empty` at the end if you want an empty string instead of `null`.